# How to save an array of doubles to a TIFF file in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, save, double, tiff

Although it seems a trivial issue, but I am really not able to find how to save a two-dimensional array of doubles to a tiff file with matlab. I tried imwrite function but this doesn't preseve the double precision information. Is there any other solution please?

Comment: You probably need to use the low-level interface to libtiff: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, do you know please how to set the Photometric parameter of the tiff object to save a 2D array of doubles (for sure it should be not set to RGB, but I don't know which should I choose (MinIsWhite, MinIsBlack, Palette, Mask, Separated, YCbCr, CIELab, ICCLab, ITULab, LogL,LogLUV, CFA, LinearRaw)

Comment: Photometric interpretation should be MinIsBlack, this indicates a normal gray-scale image.

Comment: The most important thing is to set `'SampleFormat'` to IEEEFP, and set the right bit depth.